# bowls/dirty bowls/dishes/dirty dishes

Tags: word-choice

I have two friends over and serve us a bowl of ice cream each. My friends barely eat anything. After that I take the **bowls** to the kitchen and puts them in the sink.

In this example where it's only three bowls (and three spoons) I carry out, would you use *bowls*, *dirty bowls*, *dishes*, *dirty dishes*?

Comment: There are no rules about this! Yes, _dishes_ can be a general term for tableware that has been used at a meal. You can call them what you like, however many there are and however little your friends ate.

Comment: In this example I'd use put them, not puts them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, by stating they are **dirty** you emphasise how dirty the dishes are. A bowl is a dish so you can use *dish*/*dishes* as well.

In your example:

> After that I take the bowls to the kitchen and puts them in the sink.

Change *puts* to *put*:

> After that I take the bowls to the kitchen and **put** them in the sink.

You are talking about yourself, so there is no need for *puts*. Use *puts* when talking about another person:

> After that **he** takes the bowls to the kitchen and **puts** them in the sink.